# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django

for some reason I cannot seem to solve this bug. I am using Django 3.0.5 and i am really new

The actual error I get is

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<article_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

In my project dir I have this urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.presse, name='listings'),
    path('<int:article_id>', views.article, name='article'),
]
```

My view looks like this

```
def article(request, article_id):
  article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=article_id)

  context = {
    'article': article
  }

  return render(request, 'article/article.html', context)
```

this my main page views

```
def index(request):
    designs = DesignPage.objects.order_by('-published_date').filter(is_published=True)
    articles = Article.objects.all()[::1]
    articlel = articles[0:1]
    articleS = articles[1:2]
    articleN = articles[2:3]
    articleA = articles[3:4]
    articleB = articles[4:5]
    articleC = articles[5:6]
    context = {
        'designs': designs,
        'articles': articles,
        'articlel': articlel,
        'articleS': articleS,
        'articleN': articleN,
        'articleA': articleA,
        'articleB': articleB,
        'articleC': articleC


    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

and my html is

```
<h4 class="uk-margin-small-bottom"><a href="{% url 'article' article.id %}">
```

Comment: NoReverseMatch at / ->  show us html and function for your index page ( listings?)

it does seem you are having listing urls without proper id thus resulting in error

Comment: when i used {% for article in articles %} the issued is fixed but get another problem the item replicate each time